# Селектор #/id в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется на странице блок с `id` `"/text/text"`
Необходимо с помощью jquery обратиться к нему. Пробую так - `$("#/text/text")`, но получаю ошибку связанную с неправильным выражением. Мешает именно первый `"/"`, так как без него все нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document.getElementById('/test/test'))`

Answer (score 2):

Экранируйте символ `/` двойным обратным слешем:

```js
function func() {
  $('#\\/text\\/text').text('test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="/text/text"><div>
<button onclick="func()">Проверить</button>
```

[Подробнее в документации](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).